# Is it safe to run power up to attic and back down to another outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I installed a behind tv wall hole so i can plug my tv in.  Now in trying to decide how to run power to it but I'm not an electrician.  I know that you can wire an outlet off of an existing one, but is it safe to run the cable up to the attic and back down a stud over?  The issue is that the closest existing outlet is one stud over from my new outlet.  I figured if i could just run it up and over, i could easily supply power to this new outlet.  Rather than running it to a junction or something (again, not an electrician).

Comment: Yep you can do that.  (fWIW, I always make certain to cut those behind the TV outlet holes in the same joist space as the existing outlet )

Comment: @Tyson I wanted to cut it in the same space but if i had, you would've been able to see it because the tv wouldn't have covered it. And due to limited wall space, my tv is mounted in the most optimal position.  A real bummer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's nothing wrong with this

It's A-OK to run a cable up through the top plate to the attic and back down to the next stud bay as long as the cable is run properly (1.5" setback from the edge of the studs, and run stapled to the top plate in the attic).

Comment: Because it would require ripping more dry wall and subsequently having to repair it.  If there were an easy way to run a spade bit blindly at a 45 degree angle then i probably would.  Any suggestions you have are greatly appreciated.